# Idea for testing In App Purchases on iOS; the currency displayed

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, currency, number-formatting

As I am testing In App Purchases of my app project (for iOS) at the moment, I am trying to figure out how to test for users from different countries(if the number-formatting code is correct for currencies/prices being displayed):

- What I can do is; change the country of my apple ID. Which is fine, for testing the displayed price. This price changes indeed for different countries.
- But still the displayed currency is the Euro (as I live/work and am located at the moment in Europe).

So how could I mimic/simulate being in another country/continent?
Is there another solution? 
(besides travelling....just for testing purposes :)!!)

Pls correct me if I ask something stupid or if it is already asked (I could not find a similar question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the application region in the scheme settings.

Go to `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme`. Then under Run select the Options tab, here you can easily change the region (and language) settings:

[image: Scheme settings]